# I need to write a powershell script to modify the data in SharePoint document llibrary

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I have a document library with folder structure in my SharePoint site. These folders have PDFs with multiple versions. Now, some PDFs have the same Title value but ModelNumbers are different and another field OSNumber may or may not be different. I need to take the latest PDF version (identified by Modified column value) of same Title and add older PDF's ModelNumber field value into this latest PDF ModelNumber field.

After that, I have to check OSNumber field also, if all the OSNumber of older PDFs are in newer one, then I need to delete older PDFs otherwise, if some OSNumber are not in newer PDF then I need not to delete the older PDF. Here I am explaining little more:
Need to do for each duplicate Title:

1. Collect all PDF filenames with Metadata
2. Find out what is the newest PDF file, and old PDFs, based on Modified-Date
3. Copy all ModelNumbers from the old PDFs to the newest PDF

And also: For the old PDFs:

1. Delete all OSNumbers that also exist in the newest PDF
2. Delete the ‘old’ PDF files in case the OSNumber field became empty.

Comment: Can you provide your own code? SO is NOT a script writing service, we expect effort from the users.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [iTextSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) for parsing and manipulation pdfs.

for example if you want the title of a pdf:

```
Add-Type -Path .\itextsharp.dll
$reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader -ArgumentList "$pwd\example.pdf"
Write-Output $reader.Info.Title
```